# Initiate Workflow With Custom Action

Tags: workflow, custom-actions

I have looked around on Google, and I have found tutorials on how to initiate a workflow from a custom action in the ribbon,  but I have run into a problem.  I am not sure why (I assume I have a setting wrong that isn't mentioned in the tutorials) but the drop-down under 'Initiate Workflow' in the Custom Action creation dialog contains no workflows at all.  I have tried creating test workflows of both site and reusable types.  I have several existing workflows that are associated with this list, and I have tried creating test list-associated workflows as well.  Does anyone know why I wouldn't be able to see my workflows here?

**EDIT:** I have no idea what the problem was, but I used the URL location of the initiation form, and now the 'Initiate Workflow' drop-down shows my workflows.  Guess it fixed itself...

Comment: Are your worflows associated with the list or just with the content types in the list. This could be a possible reason why you don't see any workflows.

Answer (score 0):

Under the list ribbon

New Quick Step

- Launch Application
- start an existing workflow
- add label and image
- press Okay

This should now add a button to your Item ribbon

Activation requires selection of a List Item first